# How to run a matrix column by column in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, matrix

I am running a matrix off of a nested for loop. My problem here is that the values come out wrong because the loop fills the matrix row by row. I would like to have the loop fill the matrix column by column to avoid this issue.

```
T_i = 85;                 %Initial temperature (K)
T_inf = 20;               %Free stream temperature (K)
h = 50;                   %Convection heat transfer coefficient (W/m^2K)
alp = 0.0000015;             %Thermal diffusivity (m^2/s)
k = 15;                    %Thermal conductivity (W/mK)
del_x = 0.03;             %Incremental distance between center nodes (m)
del_t = 300;                %Incremental time diference (s)

Fo = alp*del_t/(del_x^2)     %Find the Numerical/Discretized Fourier Number
Bi = h*del_x/k             %Find the Numerical/Discretized Biot Number
T__vec = [85;85;85;85]     %Initial temperature vector for 4 node points.
%T_inf_vec = 20+zeros(1:10)


M=5             %No. of rows
N=10             %No. of columns


T_inf_vec = [20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20]


A=zeros(M,N);
A(1:4)= T__vec;
A = [T_inf_vec;A];



 for i=2:M
     for j=2:N
         T_p1=(2*Fo*A(i+1,j-1))+(2*Bi*Fo*A(i-1,j-1))+(((1-2*Fo)-(2*Bi*Fo))*A(i,j-1))
 T_p11 = Fo*A(i-1,j-1)-2*Fo*A(i,j-1)+A(i,j-1)+Fo*A(i+1,j-1);
          if i==2
          A(i,j)= T_p1
          elseif i<1
          A(i,j)= 20
          else
          A(i,j)= T_p11
          end
      end
  end
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

Change the for loop by:

```
 for j=2:M
     for i=2:N
         T_p1=(2*Fo*A(i+1,j-1))+(2*Bi*Fo*A(i-1,j-1))+(((1-2*Fo)-(2*Bi*Fo))*A(i,j-1))
         T_p11 = Fo*A(i-1,j-1)-2*Fo*A(i,j-1)+A(i,j-1)+Fo*A(i+1,j-1);
         if i==2
             A(i,j)= T_p1
         elseif i<1
             A(i,j)= 20
         else
             A(i,j)= T_p11
         end
      end
  end
```